# Exiting from Native code in JNI kills Java application

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-native-interface, native

I am calling a method of my native dll from JNI. It works fine but at one place in a my native code, I am calling exit(1) so that native code stops working but what happens is that it also causes to exit from my java application. Am I missing something? Is there any method in JNI so that I can only kill native code instead of whole java application?

**Edit:** Basically I am encrypting a file in native code. I want it to stop encrypting when some one cancels the operation from java.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "native code stops"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JNI native code and the JVM run in the same process. Since `exit` shuts down the process, it will also end the JVM.

Killing a thread which executes in native code is potentially leaking resources and therefore not supported. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633924/java-how-to-stop-a-thread-thats-calling-a-succession-of-c-functions-using-a) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If in a separate thread in the native code, just stop.

```
//sample thread code
void thread(){
  while (1) {
    //do something
    if ( done ) return;
  }
}
```

If you're in a native function and you want to return back into Java, just  return.

If you have made a tangled maze of function calls and loop; all alike, and need to get out,
then throw a native exception, catching it at the last native level and return.
This is so not recommended it should be un-recommended, but sometimes you might get into this sort of mess.

```
// Do not write code like this
// A kitten and a puppy die every time you call it
void foo(){
  while (1){
     bar();
  }
}

void bar(){
  for( i=0; i < 100; i++){
    baz();
    quux();
  }
}

void baz(){
 // something
}

void quux(){
 // something
 if( want_to_exit) throw new GetOut();
}

void JNI_Method(.....){
   try {
     if (x) foo();
   } catch ( GetOut g){
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if every android implementation of the stdc++ implements the exceptions mecanism...

Comment: @Geoffroy Question is tagged windows not android

Comment: Ouch sorry :) To used to see jni associated with android ;)

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is to run encryption code in separate thread and terminate the newly created thread with terminatethread() from the main thread when the need arises but the problem is that terminatethread() does not release resources (file handles etc) in time and I am not able to delete the file from java immediately after the thread is closed.